# Search label and description using JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This is my current code

```
    $( "#part_numbers<?php echo $i ?>" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( "; " );
                return false;
            }


        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
              .append("<a>" + item.label + " - (" + item.desc + ") <img alt='no image' style='height: 50px;' src='./images/" + item.file + "' /></a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

I want to be able to search on the description as well and was able to find this example

```
source: function (request, response) {
var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
response($.grep(schools, function(value) {
    return matcher.test(value.value)
        || matcher.test(value.nickname);
}));
}
```

I've wrestled with this for a while now and resorted to just randomly testing different things but haven't been able to search both the label and description.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data, what is `availableTags`?

Comment: availableTags is dynamically created but ends up looking something like  
   var availableTags = [
{ value: "", label: "", desc: "", file: "", vendor: "" },{ value: "00-1156-02", label: "00-1156-02", desc: "", file: "", vendor: "" },{ value: "00-1156-03", label: "00-1156-03", desc: "", file: "", vendor: "" }];

Comment: Sounds similar to your last question that was not marked answered.

Comment: I got past the issue with the last question "using multiple tags"  I just can't figure out searching using the tag and the description.

Comment: My point is that it can be helpful to mark an answer as the one that worked for you. This is helpful to others that may come across the post in the future. I see you have asked a number of questions yet never marked an answer for any of them.

Comment: In regards to your question, you will want to build an array or object of the result you want to send back to `response()` and then you can populate it with the `availableTags` that hit for your `term`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, basically you have to apply 2 filters, capture all your data, and then send it back to `response()` in 1 array.

If your data is like:

```
var availableTags = [{
  value: "", 
  label: "", 
  desc: "", 
  file: "", 
  vendor: "" 
},{ 
  value: "00-1156-02", 
  label: "00-1156-02", 
  desc: "", 
  file: "", 
  vendor: "" 
}];
```

You can setup a source like:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
  // extract the last term
  var lastTerm = extractLast(request.term);
  var results = [];
  // loop over data, seeking labels & desc
  $.each(availableTags, function(k, v){
    if(v.label.indexOf(lastTerm) => 0){
      results.push(v);
    }
    if(v.desc.indexOf(lastTerm) => 0){
      results.push(v);
    }
  });
  response(results);
}
```

Personally, since you're already using PHP, I would set your source to a PHP page that performs this query in the SQL Database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I keep getting  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . on this line                             if(v.label.indexOf(lastTerm) => 0){     This happens on both if statements however if I delete both if statements the code runs fine (except it returns all tags of course)

Comment: @Jeremy I suspect something is happening in `extractLast()` such that it is not returning a string. Not sure without seeing all code.

Comment: Sorry to beat this into the ground but I'm having trouble going through this code line by line to even figure out what everything is doing.  Here are the extractLast(); related functions which combined with the above code is all the code for this --------- function split( val ) {
   return val.split( /;\s*/ );
  }
  function extractLast( term ) {
   return split( term ).pop();
  }